# Chinese text not working in terminal

Tags: sqlite, macos, terminal

I'm trying to paste chinese text into terminal but I just get lots of numbers instead. if I quickly paste as soon as terminal loads the paste will work that once but not again? Its utf-8 unicode i'm using.

I dont think its the font as it works in textedit the only place I get the problem is in terminal but I need to use it to make my sqlite database.

What would be the best thing to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load `Terminal Inspector`, and make sure the `Character Set Encoding` has to be set to `Unicode (UTF-8)` and check the `Wide glyphs for Japanese/Chinese/etc`  setting.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do would probably be to write the data into an SQL file and perform that with `sqlite3 mydatabase.db < mychinesetextfile.sql`.

It's not pretty, on the whole; but it'll work.

Comment: The database ends in .sql will that make a difference?

Comment: I tried copying and pasting into to terminal to try and make a new.db that way but I just end up with 331\212\331\205\331\220....

Comment: it now appears in terminal but when I try to use sqlite it just gives me lots of numbers.